# Why does formals function return NULL on functions defined with arguments?

Tags: r

From base **R**, **formals** function should grant access and allow manipulation of the Formal Arguments. 
So, why does it return **NULL** on some functions defined with classic arguments ?

```
> ls
function (name, pos = -1L, envir = as.environment(pos), all.names = FALSE, 
    pattern, sorted = TRUE) 
{ ...

> formals(ls)
$name


$pos
-1L

$envir
as.environment(pos)

$all.names
[1] FALSE

$pattern


$sorted
[1] TRUE


> sum
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
> formals(sum)
NULL
```

I expect formals(sum) to provide a length two list result, not **NULL**

Comment: From [`?formals`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/formals): *"Only _closures_ have formals, not primitive functions. ... returns ... NULL for a non-function or primitive"*. Many low-level functions (including `sum` as you've shown on this console output) are `.Primitive` functions, which `formals` will not be able to inspect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your choice of function is apparent from its body. Primitive functions are somewhat different in that their argument list may have some names but their arguments are passed to C code and `formals()`, `body()`, and `environment()`  all return `NULL`. Try it with `apply` instead.